# Cannot determine compatible version of visual studio for this uri

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-mobile-services

Trying to open DataBase from Microsoft Azure mobile service. The following URI is called:

```
vsweb://vs/?product=Visual_Studio&encformat=...
```

Ad the following error as result:

```
"cannot determine compatible version of visual studio for this uri"
```

What application I need to open that DB? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
vsweb://vs/?product=Visual_Studio&encformat=...
```

Can you try

```
vsweb://vs/?Product=Visual_Studion&Gen=2013&EncFormat=...
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS 2013 then please download Update 4 for VS 2013. i have the same problem. but just recentlty I got solut